# console.log messages showing at the end of script execution

Tags: javascript

I'm Just starting out with Javascript here and was making a simple todolist

The code below is working but I'm unable to see console messages or the webpage until the executions ends (when I enter "quit")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Todo list</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Magic.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todo list</h1>

    <ul>
        <li>new - to add to list</li>
        <li>list - to show the list</li>
        <li>delete - to delete an item</li>
        <li>quit - to quit the list</li>

    </ul>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Magic.js"></script>
</html>
```

this is the html and below is the java script

```
console.log("CONNECTED!!!");
alert("CONNECTED");
var input = prompt("What do you wanna do??");
var todoList = ["Groccery"];
while(input!=="quit")
{
    if(input === "new")
    {
        addTodo();
    }
    else if(input === "list")
    {
        listTodo();
    }
    else if(input === "delete")
    {
        deleteTodo();
    }
    input = prompt("what do you wanna do next");
}

console.log("OKK YOU QUIT");

function addTodo()
{
    newItem = prompt("Enter the item to be added");
    todoList.push(newItem);
    console.log("Item Added!");
}

function listTodo()
{
    console.log("*****************");
    todoList.forEach(function(todo , i){
        console.log(i  +  ": "  + todo);
    })
    console.log("*****************");
}


function deleteTodo()
{
    index = prompt("Enter the index of the Item to be deleted ");
    todoList.splice(index , 1);

}
```

[connected as alert  but nothing in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMcSf.png)

[entered new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2BfC.png)

[new item as "space"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEuDM.png)

[Listing but nothing in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjxIH.png)

[quitting now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjskN.png)

[at the end the html is loaded and also i see everything in console as it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu6Hw.png)

Comment: Why is the script listed twice?

Comment: alert(), prompt() and other modal message boxes block the js / ui thread nothing can happen while those are going on. And since you are in a loop of alerts, prompt, etc nothing will show till the end

Comment: So what is the work around, Im trying to learn basics in js like working on arrays , objects.. it'd be gr8 if i could see those log messages at runtime